# Ajax call MVC dropdown after another dropdown selected - Keep selected after refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Dropdownlist. On its selection, another Dropdownlist is called in a AJAX Call. its working fine, but, on page refresh I'm missing the selected option.

**MY VIEW - Dropdown-1**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 form-group">
    <label class="font-noraml">Empresa</label>
     <div class="input-group">
          @Html.DropDownList("IdCliente", null, "SELECIONE A EMPRESA", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control combo2", required = true, @id = "IdCliente", @onchange = "javascript:GetFiltros(this.value);" })
     </div>
</div>
```

**MY VIEW - Dropdown-2**

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
     <label>Condomínio</label>
      <select disabled id="codCond" name="codCond" style="width: 100%">
            <option selected="selected">TODOS</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

**MY JS AJAX**

```
if ($("#IdCliente").val() != '') {
                GetFiltros($("#IdCliente").val());
            }

function GetFiltros(_idCLiente) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Analytics/FiltroCondominio/",
                data: { cliente: _idCLiente },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {                   
                    if (data == "") {
                        swal({ type: "warning", title: "Alerta", text: "Esta Empresa não possui configuração de Conexão, por favor entre em contato com a equipe de suporte.", timer: 10000, showConfirmButton: true });
                    }
                    else {
                        var $codCond = $('#codCond');
                        $codCond.empty();
                        $('#codCond').prop("disabled", false);
                        $("#codCond").append("<option value=''>TODOS</option>");
                        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                            $('<option>', { value: data[x].Value }).html(data[x].Text).appendTo($codCond);
                        };
                    }
                },
                error: function (reponse) {
                    alert("error : " + reponse);
                }
            });
        }
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FiltroCondominio(string cliente)
{
     var cond = new SelectList(new AnalyticsData().GetFiltroCond(cliente), "CD_CLIENTE", "CONDOMINIO");

      return Json(cond);
}
```

When I choose the option and press the load button it brings the results and on refresh bring the dropdownlist-2 selected, to all again (TODOS).

**MY MVC GET**

```
 public ActionResult AcessosUsuarios()
        {
            var cliData = new LicenciadoData();
            var usuario = new UsuarioData();
            var _userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();           
            string cliente = cliData.GetPartnerId(usuario.GetId_Cliente(_userId));

            var agora = DateTime.Now;
            var start = agora.AddDays(-30);
            var end = agora.AddDays(-1);

            ViewBag.Data1 = start.ToShortDateString();
            ViewBag.Data2 = end.ToShortDateString();               
            ViewBag.ListaUsuarios = "";
            ViewBag.IdCliente = new SelectList(cliData.ListarPainel(_userId), "Id", "Fantasia");

            if (User.IsInRole("CLIENTE"))
            {
                var IdCliente = new UsuarioData().GetId_Cliente(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                ViewBag.codCond = new SelectList(new AnalyticsData().GetFiltroCond(cliente), "CD_CLIENTE", "CONDOMINIO");   
            }
            return View();
        }
```

**MY MVC POST**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AcessosUsuarios(string data1, string data2, int? codCond, int? IdCliente, string listaCheia)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IdCliente.ToString()))
            {
                var cliData = new LicenciadoData();
                string cliente = cliData.GetPartnerId(IdCliente);

                var AcessosUsuarios = new List<ListAcess>();
                var ListaUsuarios = new List<ListUserAccess>();
                var TotalUsuarios = new List<UserTotal>();
                var TotalAcessos = new List<ListAcess>();

                AcessosUsuarios = new AnalyticsData().GetAcessoUsuarios(cliente, codCond, data1, data2);
                ListaUsuarios = new AnalyticsData().GetListaUsuarios(cliente, codCond);

                ViewBag.ListaUsuarios = ListaUsuarios;
                ViewBag.Condominio = new AnalyticsData().GetCondominio(cliente, codCond);

                ViewBag.Data1 = data1;
                ViewBag.Data2 = data2;
                ViewBag.Filtro = codCond ?? 0;

                ViewBag.IdCliente = new SelectList(cliData.ListarPainel(User.Identity.GetUserId()), "Id", "Fantasia");
                ViewBag.codCond = new SelectList(new AnalyticsData().GetFiltroCond(cliente), "CD_CLIENTE", "CONDOMINIO", codCond);

                if (User.IsInRole("CLIENTE"))
                {
                    ViewBag.codCond = new SelectList(new AnalyticsData().GetFiltroCond(cliente), "CD_CLIENTE", "CONDOMINIO", codCond);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var cliData = new LicenciadoData();

                TempData["cliente"] = "0";
                ViewBag.IdCliente = new SelectList(cliData.Listar(User.Identity.GetUserId()), "Id", "Fantasia");

                if (User.IsInRole("CLIENTE"))
                {
                    ViewBag.codCond = new SelectList(new KiperServerData(IdCliente).GetListaCond(), "Cod", "Nome", codCond);
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You would need to store the page state either in localStorage, cookie or server side and make adjustments on reload

Comment: what do you mean on refresh? ajax doesnt cause a page refresh and i dont see anywhere in your code youre manually triggering one. it looks like you just need to set the selected option. if anything, you can verify options exist and mark options as selected in the `success` callback for your ajax call if you need to. it also seems like the ajax call should be triggered `onchange` of the first dropdown list which I dont see in your posted code

Comment: note if youre saying the issue occurs when you manually trigger a refresh by clicking the page refresh button in the browser, then please refer to @charlietfl 's comment.

Comment: Thanks for answers. @GregH my Ajax is just for my dropdown, actualy its a regular MVC GET and POST action. I will EDIT and i will add my GET and POST method.

Comment: if you need to persist any client side state through a request/response then as @charlietfl said, you need to either store it in localStorage, cookie storage or you can include it in the viewmodel that you're passing around and set the selected item with that property